# Fast Enumeration with NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, 64-bit

I found a weird issue with 64 bit platform, when i tried to enumerate NSMutableDictionary.I have a code as follows,

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSArray *expectedKeysArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"K1", @"K2", @"K3", @"K4", @"K5", nil];
NSArray *expectedValuesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"V1", @"V2", @"V3", @"V4", @"V5", nil];
for (int i = 0; i < [expectedKeysArray count]; i++) {
    [dictionary setObject:[expectedValuesArray objectAtIndex:i]
                        forKey:[expectedKeysArray objectAtIndex:i]];
}
 for (NSString *key in dictionary) {
    NSLog(@"key %@",key);

}
```

When i ran the above code in 32 bit simulator,line within the for loop

```
 NSLog(@"key %@",key);
```

is getting executed and fast enumeration works fine.But when i run the above code in 64 bit simulator, it doesn't even enter the for loop and fast enumeration doesn't work.Did anyone face a similar issue?.I'm using Xcode 5.1,with iOS 7.1

Comment: @Prince : I'm using Xcode 5.1,with iOS 7.1.

Comment: me too but i don't see any unwanted behaviour of looping as you have issue with.One question is it ARC?

Comment: @Prince : yes its ARC

Comment: That code works fine in my 64-bit iOS Simulator. Is it your exact code? What does `NSLog(@"%@", dictionary);` show ?

Comment: Unrelated to your bug: look up +dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:.